# Angular 8 Route Refresh gives 404 on Deployment Server

Tags: html, angular

i am developing the application using Angular 8. I am facing an issue on the deployment server. When i make a build and deploy it to the server. If i go through its index point then its working fine but if i refresh any route then its giving me 404 error. kindly suggest me the best solution.

I implemented the hash strategy too on my local and checked on iis windows its working fine but i need some other method so that url will not look ugly. In this strategy a hash always would be there in the url.

So please tell is there any other way to do it.. without showing # in url..

Please experts help me to fix this as like angular.io because on that if you refresh any route then its work good without hashing strategy...

Comment: Show your webserver config

Comment: where to see that in cpanel ..? can you guide david

Comment: You should have a server information link or something similar. Look for Apache or Nginx, they are the most popular ones

Answer (score 0):

I usually use hash strategy but, as I know it is possibile to configure your server (for example via `.htaccess` file) in order to configure your routing. I don't know how by the way.